# Compare Array with up to 100 item id's (containing duplicates) to array with unique id's

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to count how many times numbers from arr1 appear in arr2. I tried intersects with sets however I do not wish to remove duplicates.

```
var arr1 = [1,4,5,7]

func compareCount(arr2[Int])-> Int {
    //arr2 = 1,1,4,5,6,6,3,9,7,7,7,1,7


    return count 
    //returns 9 as there are 9 elements within arr2 that exist within arr1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NSCountedSet` for that:

```
var arr1 = [1,4,5,7]
var arr2 = [1,1,4,5,6,6,3,9,7,7,7,1,7]
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: arr2)
```

Then, iterate through `arr1` and for each, you'll get easily the number of occurences with `count(for:)`, and with reduce, you can add them:

```
let numberOfOccurences = arr1.reduce(into: 0) { (result, current) in
    let numberOfOccurencesForCurrent = countedSet.count(for: current)
    result += numberOfOccurencesForCurrent
}

print("numberOfOccurences: \(numberOfOccurences)")
```

Edit:

If you don't want to use `reduce()` (because you want to avoid using it without understanding it), but rather do a more simple loop:

```
var numberOfOccurences = 0
arr1.forEach({ numberOfOccurences += countedSet.count(for: $0) })
```

Comment: Naice answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Loop the first array and count every filtered elements in the second one

```
var count = 0
arr1.forEach( { value in
    count += arr2.filter( {$0 == value} ).count
})
```

Comment: liked this solution :)